# Does the nativescript app with IOS platform works perfectly in iPad?

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript, nativescript

I am new to nativescript and I'm creating an app for ios and android. I tried running it in android phone and iPhone, it works perfectly but I haven't tried running it in iPad yet.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the reason of your question? It works as perfectly on iPad as it does on iPhone, but perhaps there's something specific you're wondering about?

Comment: Actually I am new to nativescript and I'm creating an app for ios and android. I tried running it in android phone and iPhone, it works perfectly but I haven't tried running it in iPad yet. @EddyVerbruggen

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your app to a simulator to test it on iPad. Should work just fine. You may want to increase fontsizes a bit, but the way to do that depends on whether you're using NativeScript with or without Angular.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Sorry for that